# React Failed to customise Material UI button

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

I was using this package material UI for a project. The version is rather old(v1) as I need it to be compatible to the project itself(using node 10.8)

Right now I am trying to use a round button (see [this demo](https://v1.material-ui.com/demos/buttons/)) I was trying to use a round mini button, it worked pretty well when I am not using any theme.

```
<Button
      id={this.props.id}
      variant="fab" mini  
      onClick={this.props.onClick}
      color={this.state.clicked ?  "primary" : 'default' }>
      {sth}
</Button>
```

Then I was trying to change the colour of the button. I added a theme and use that theme to wrap on the button.

This is not the first time I did such thing, as I changed the colour for a number of buttons before by doing this(they're all rectangular contained buttons).

```
const confirm_theme = createMuiTheme({
  palette: {
    primary: {
      main: '#006D8F',
      contrastText: '#fff',
    },
  },
});

export class StyledButton extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      clicked: false,
    };
  }
 
  handleClick = (e) => {
    this.setState({ clicked: !this.state.clicked });
  }
  
  render(){
    return (
      <Row 
      style={{ paddingTop: 10, justifyContent: "center"}}>
        <MuiThemeProvider theme={confirm_theme}>
          <Button
            variant="contained"
            id={this.props.id}
            onClick={this.props.onClick}
            color={this.state.clicked ? 'default' : "primary"}>
            {sth}
            </Button>
        </MuiThemeProvider>
      </Row>
    )
  }
  
}
```

However, this time I failed to do so, when I use it on a round mini button.
There were no error messages, and the colour of the button has been changed successfully, but the button went blank.

Has anyone encountered something like this? Is it possible to fix?(I know my version is quite old, so I understand there might not be a solution)

Comment: did you flip the default and primary values on purpose? 
`color={this.state.clicked ? 'default' : "primary"}`

Comment: @DJBurb yes, as I want the primary colour to be shown on default(button state should be clicked=false by default).

Answer (score 0):

Your `handleClick` function is never triggered.

So instead of passing `this.props.onClick` to the button component you can pass the `handleClick` function and then call your `this.props.onClick` function inside the `handleClick`.

```js
const confirm_theme = createMuiTheme({
  palette: {
    primary: {
      main: '#006D8F',
      contrastText: '#fff',
    },
  },
});

export class StyledButton extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      clicked: false,
    };
  }
 
  handleClick = (e) => {
    this.setState({ clicked: !this.state.clicked });
    this.props.onClick();
  }
  
  render(){
    return (
      <Row 
      style={{ paddingTop: 10, justifyContent: "center"}}>
        <MuiThemeProvider theme={confirm_theme}>
          <Button
            variant="contained"
            id={this.props.id}
            onClick={this.handleClick}
            color={this.state.clicked ? 'default' : "primary"}>
            {sth}
            </Button>
        </MuiThemeProvider>
      </Row>
    )
  }
  
}
```

### Live demo:

[image: Edit fervent-lewin-cb5k6]